# Increment by 1 when using .map and a condition evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

Im having a hard time incrementing by 1 when I use `.map` to loop through array `myClasses` and when `status` in the array is equal to 'Open' or 'In Progress' increment a number by 1. My goal is to have the total number of classes that are either 'Open' or 'In Progress'

**This is what Im currently doing**

```
myClasses.map(a => (a.status === ('Open' || 'In Progress') ? 'Yes' : 'No'))
```

currently when a class is Open or In Progress I just output either a `yes` or `no` but I want to be able to add a 1 or 0 to a number variable.

**This is what myClasses array contains**

```
0: {id: "0000AK",  type: "Elective", status: "Open"       } 
1: {id: "597WUK",  type: "Core",     status: "Closed"     } 
2: {id: "082HCE",  type: "Core",     status: "In Progress"} 
3: {id: "091HSN",  type: "Elective", status: "Canceled"   } 
4: {id: "038GAQ",  type: "Core",     status: "Open"       }
```

Right now my output looks like this `Yes,No,Yes,No,Yes` instead I want the output to be `3`

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: `('Open' || 'In Progress')` will always evaluate to `"Open"` because it's a truthy value. You should use `if(['Open', 'In Progress'].includes(a.status))`.

Comment: Your condition `a.status === ('Open' || 'In Progress')` is wrong. Rewrite it as  `(a.status === 'Open' ||  a.status === 'In Progress')`

Comment: why do you need to take map, if you like to get a single value?

Comment: In addition to the change to the comparison that others suggested, you should also use `filter()` instead of `map()` here. Then the count is just the length of the resulting array. Alternatively you can use `reduce()` to sum a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its just the count you're after, you could simply use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and get the `length` of the array returned

```js
const myClasses = [{id:"0000AK",type:"Elective",status:"Open"},{id:"597WUK",type:"Core",status:"Closed"},{id:"082HCE",type:"Core",status:"In Progress"},{id:"091HSN",type:"Elective",status:"Canceled"},{id:"038GAQ",type:"Core",status:"Open"}];

const count = myClasses.filter(a => a.status === 'Open' || a.status === 'In Progress').length

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the count into the true part of the ternary.

```js
var myClasses = [{ id: "0000AK", type: "Elective", status: "Open" }, { id: "597WUK", type: "Core", status: "Closed" }, { id: "082HCE", type: "Core", status: "In Progress" }, { id: "091HSN", type: "Elective", status: "Canceled" }, { id: "038GAQ", type: "Core", status: "Open" }],
    count = 0,
    result = myClasses.map(({ status }) => status === 'Open' || status === 'In Progress'
        ? (count++, 'Yes')
        : 'No'
    );

console.log(count);
console.log(result);
```

To get just the count, you coud reduce the array. If you like to check more values, you coudl take an array or a `Set` and check if the data structure contains an element.

```js
var myClasses = [{ id: "0000AK", type: "Elective", status: "Open" }, { id: "597WUK", type: "Core", status: "Closed" }, { id: "082HCE", type: "Core", status: "In Progress" }, { id: "091HSN", type: "Elective", status: "Canceled" }, { id: "038GAQ", type: "Core", status: "Open" }],
    wanted = ['Open', 'In Progress'],
    count = myClasses.reduce((c, { status }) => c + wanted.includes(status), 0);

 console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about ? Array reduce

```
const data = [
  { id: '0000AK', type: 'Elective', status: 'Open' },
  { id: '597WUK', type: 'Core', status: 'Closed' },
  { id: '082HCE', type: 'Core', status: 'In Progress' },
  { id: '091HSN', type: 'Elective', status: 'Canceled' },
  { id: '038GAQ', type: 'Core', status: 'Open' }
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const status = cur.status;
  if (status === 'Open' || status === 'In Progress') {
    return acc + 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, 0);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `reduce()` instead of `map()`:

```
var count = myClasses.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    if (item.status == 'Open' || item.status == 'In Progress') {
        return accumulator + 1;
    }
    return accumulator;
}, 0);
```

Note how I have also modified the condition in the `if` statement to compare against each of the two values that you want.